# Can I declare an integer that has a string equivalent?

Tags: java, netbeans, hashmap

I'm trying to declare an int that has an equivalent of a string like if you have an option between numbers 1-3 and if you choose 1 it will be equal to strawberry or 2 for apple 3 for banana and how do i call the string equivalent of it?  This is my Code:

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));            
        Random generate = new Random();
        int cnum = generate.nextInt(3) + 1;
        String 1 = "Scissor";
        String 2 = "Rock";
        String 3 = "Paper";
        String cmove= "";
        if (cnum ==1){
            cmove = "Scissor";}
        if (cnum ==2){
            cmove = "Rock";}
        if (cnum ==3){
            cmove = "Paper";}
        System.out.println("Select the number of your move:"
                + "\n1) Scissor"
                + "\n2) Rock"
                + "\n3) Paper ");
        int move = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if (cnum==move){
            System.out.println("Tie!");
            System.out.println("Computer Move is " +cmove);
        } else if (move==1){
                System.out.println("Your move is Scissor");
                System.out.println("Computer Move is " +cmove);

        } else if (move==2){
                System.out.println("Your move is Rock");
                System.out.println("Computer Move is " +cmove);
        } else if (move==3){
                System.out.println("Your move is Paper");
                System.out.println("Computer Move is " +cmove);
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Map:

```
Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

myMap.put(1, "Scissor");
myMap.put(2, "Rock");
myMap.put(3, "Paper");
```

In order to call the "string equivalent" you use the `get()` method:

```
myMap.get(cnum);
//etc
```

Answer (score 2):

In case if you can't use Map for any reason, another (simpler) way is to use a String array:

```
String[] fruits ={"Strawberry", "Apple", "Banana"};
int choice = rnd.nextInt(fruits.length);
System.out.println(fruits[choice]);
```